# Parse and semantic issues in TestFlight.h after installing SDK

Tags: objective-c, testflight

I installed TestFlight SDK following installation instructions and then when I tried to build my app I got more than 20 parse and semantic issues in TestFlight.h and build failed.

What is wrong with my installation?

Answer (score 0):

What I did wrong was for this step:

> 1. In your Application Delegate:
>
>    1. Import TestFlight: `#import "TestFlight.h"`

I imported it in the body instead of in the header. Just moving the import to the header solved my issue.

(Very small issue but I thought it could help some developers to save some time)